# Utilizing multiple tables with row click

Tags: jquery, datatables

TableA rows are dynamically added through ajax when a user submits a form. Ajax returns an object.
TableA rows are cleared every time the ajax is called and replaced with different data but TableB rows still remain intact.

What I'm trying to accomplish is:
- Click row on TableA, row becomes selected and pushed to TableB
- Click selected row on TableB, row becomes unselected and removed from TableB
- Click row on TableB, row is removed and unselected on TableA
- Supports shift click (multiple rows) for TableA

Here is an example: http://live.datatables.net/tiruyode/6/edit

Comment: I've tinkered with this for a while now, and haven't come up with a solution.  I just posted your live link in the DataTables forum along with a question (so don't take it down).  Let's see if we get a solution and both learn something.

Comment: I wanted to see if we could avoid adding a row index, so I asked in the datatables forum.  Allan wrote back and said to add a row index.  [Here's](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36431?) the link with Allan's comment.  Gyrocode has put a working example together for you.

Comment: My rows contain a row index - incremented id.
But the problem with his example, it only uses the current selected rows in tablea, which doesn't work properly for me because the rows are dynamic and changed when user submits a 'form'. And can be submitted as many times as needed.

Comment: Ok. So what do you want to do if a row in TableB is selected that isn't in TableA at that time?

Comment: To simply be removed. if it exists in tablea, unselect it:

Comment: It looks like Gyrocode's samples do what you need.  What's missing?

Comment: Only be removed if it's deselected and clicked from TableA or TableB.  His code only utilizes the current selected rows in TableA.  So if I query new rows for TableA and attempt to select it, it will replace all the old rows in TableB which I need to keep.

Comment: In that case I suggest that you pull the primary id for each record along with your ajax call, and use that to keep track of which records are which.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```js
var tablea = $('#tablea').DataTable({
    select: {
        style: 'multi+shift'
    },
    order: []
});

var tableb = $('#tableb').DataTable({
    select: {
        style: 'multi+shift'
    },
    order: []
});


tablea.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {
  // Add extra data element containing table A row index
  var tableData=[];     
  tablea.rows({ selected: true }).every(function(rowIdx){
    var rowData = this.data();
    rowData.push(rowIdx);
    tableData.push(rowData);
  });

  // Add all selected rows to table B 
  tableb
    .clear()
    .rows.add(tableData)
    .draw();
});

tableb.on('select.dt', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {
  tableb.rows({ selected: true }).every(function(rowIdx){
    // Retrieve table A row index
    var tableARowIdx = this.data().pop();

    // Deselect row in table A
    tablea.row(tableARowIdx).deselect();
  });
});
```

See [this example](http://live.datatables.net/qabiguje/3) for code and demonstration.

If your data source is objects retrieved via Ajax, you can see [this example](http://live.datatables.net/qabiguje/6) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I guess something I forgot to mention, the rows are dynamic.. Populated from a database when a user searches for something.
So clearing and adding selected rows won't work.

Comment: @HoulaBanada, please edit original question adding more details and/or example.

Comment: did that. Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: @HoulaBanada, I updated the answer but the code doesn't change much, the principle is the same.